# Parse-JS-SDK, the matchesKeyInQuery not work with objectId。

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

`javascript
 "parse-server": "^2.6.3",
  "parse": "^1.10.0",`

I have three Table， `Member` 、 `Circle` and `MemberCircle` 。

`Circle` has a pointer field named `member`，it means who create the `circle` 。

And `MemberCircle` has two pointer filed, `member` and `circle`。 the `member` means who join the circle。

I want to query the circles which the member create and join。but the `matchesKeyInQuery` seens not work with the `objectId`。

```
const member = new Parse.Object('Member')
member.id = 'memberid'
const queryPage = new Parse.Query('Circle')
const queryOwn = queryPage.equalTo('member', member).equalTo('status', 1)
const queryJoin = new Parse.Query('Circle').matchesKeyInQuery('objectId', 'circle', new Parse.Query('MemberCircle').equalTo('member', member))
```

Parse.Query.or(queryOwn, queryJoin).limit(15).skip(prePage * pageSize)

How to write the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `matchesKeyInQuery` with `objectId` is now possible using dot notation in the latest release of `parse-server 2.7.2`.

Replace the `query-key` 'circle' with 'circle.objectId'

[Here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/4399) is this pull request to `parse-server` that addressed this.